# AngularJS $http PUT request

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I am buiding a CRUD apps with AngularJS and Django REST API.

I have created get and post method successfully but not getting how to put request. i tried stackoverflow lots of problem and youtube but i couldnt sort it out.

my current controller is:

```
app.controller('crudCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/?format=json")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.contacts = response.data; //this is get method that displayed all the list of contact
  });

  $scope.formModel = {}; // this is same input.js, it is POST method to to send data to database
    $scope.onSubmit = function () {
        console.log("hey, i am submitting");
        console.log($scope.formModel);

        $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel).
        success(function (data) {
            console.log(":)");
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(":(");
        });
    };


  $scope.selectUser = function (contact) {
        console.log(contact);                    // it will select the data exactly where you click
        $scope.clickedUser = contact;
    };

    $scope.updateUser = function (argument) { // it will get the form editable exactly which contact you clicked
    };

});
```

and my edit view is, when i click on edit buttion, the form will be appear:

```
<form>
      <input type="text" ng-model="clickedUser.userid">
      <input type="text"  ng-model="clickedUser.name">
      <input type="text" ng-model="clickedUser.email">
      <input type="text"  ng-model="clickedUser.phone">
      <button type="submit" ng-click="updateUser()" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**Point to be noted, the edit form working nice on client side** but it doesnt send the data to backend/API/Database.

can anyone tell me how can i do `$http.put` request? i tried w3school, youtube, and stackoverflow problem.

i got huge solution but i couldnt solve it.

this is my api endpoint for anything: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/` so if i want to update particular field, i have to go through this url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/1` in the end of the url is `id`

I hope it is clear to you

Comment: Just like `$http.post` method, `$http.put` method is also available. Please try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this as well

```
$http({method: "PUT", url: URL}).
        then(
           function(response) {
        }, function(response) {
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use angular put?

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put

```
var clientData = {
   text: "Put this somewhere"
};
$http.put( url, clientData ).then( function( serverResponse ) {
    console.log(serverResponse);
},( error )=>{
    console.log(serverError);
});
```